# Why can $T(x,c)=\theta(x),T(c,y)=\theta(y),T(x,y)=\theta(x+y)+T(x/2,y/2)$ be rewritten as $T(x,y)=c(x+y)+T(x/2,y/2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

I'm doing a self study on MIT Opencourseware Algorithms course and the first problem set can be found here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps1_sol.pdf.

In **Recurence Relations Resolution** section this is given
$$
T(x,c) = \theta(x) \text{   for } c\leq2\\
T(c,y) = \theta(y) \text{   for } c\leq2\\
T(x,y) = \theta(x+y)+T(x/2,y/2)
$$

On the first step of this solution is this:
$$
T(x,y)=c(x,y)+T(x/2,y/2)
$$

I have trouble understanding the first step. How did $\theta(x+y)$ turn into $c(x+y)$?

**Things I've done**

- I watched the 1 and 2 lecture videos here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/
- I looked at lecture notes 1 and 2 here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-notes/

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect. For example, if $T(x, y) = x + y + 2^{-x}$, then it satisfies conditions, but not the first step.

To fix it, we should write $T(x, y) \leq c\cdot(x _ y) + T(x/2, y/2)$ and get $T(x, y) \leq 2c(x, y)$ (with the same geometric sequence argument). Then we should write $T(x, y) \geq d\cdot(x + y) + T(x/2, y / 2)$ (with $d > 0$) and get $T(x, y) \geq d\cdot (x + y)$. Together it gives us $T(x, y) = \Theta(x + y)$.